# Next JS Api Route giving a 500

Tags: typescript, prisma, next.js13

```
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";



const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function GET() {
    try {
        const machines = await prisma.machines.findMany();
        console.log(machines, "machines")
        return {
            body: machines,
            status: 200
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return {
            body: { error: "An error occurred while fetching the data." },
            status: 500
        };
    }
}
```

Machines is console logging correctly but I am getting a 500 without a response body when I try and hit the route.

Other info: I am using the App router, this file is located at app > api > get > route.ts

Answer (score 0):

In Next if you'd like to return the data, it is better to use `NextResponse`.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

NextResponse.json(data, {
  status: xxx,
})
```

see the official documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json

Comment: Yep that was the issue! Thank you!